# My app shows as translated in the App Store but it isn't

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just released an update for my app to build it against ios 8 and it's now showing as being translated to a lot of languages, which isn't something I've tackled!

Is this a new issue or something anyone's seen before?

Comment: Could you link to your app in the app store?

Comment: One of my apps is having the same issue - it says it's localized in a variety of languages even though it's not localized at all. Link: [Click here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sycamore-home/id897943552?mt=8)

Comment: @rebello95 You meant that under "Languages" in App Store it is said that you have localized the app in "English, Chinese, German, " etc etc when your App is supposed to only show English?

Comment: @Unheilig Correct. None of my other apps (also recently updated) have this issue.

Comment: Any chance you added the use of a third part/open source component (e.g., appirator, sharekit) that includes translations in your most recent release? If so, that may be causing the app store to think your entire app has been translated.

Comment: Here's the link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-e-mail/id863318779?mt=8

As you say it's under Languages it lists a load of languages other than English. My previous app submissions all say English only.

It could be a third party integration I guess... I use Flurry and Crashlytics, which could feasibly cause an issue I suppose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real answers here but a subsequent update has changed it back to just English now, could well have been Flurry/Crashlytics that was causing it and an update to that inbetween resolved it.